# How to include all files in Go code coverage calculations?

Tags: go

When testing the code coverage using the following command - `go tool cover -func=func.out`,the output provides a statement total code coverage percentage (shown below).  However, I find this a bit misleading as those files without any test file are excluded from the overall percentage.

Is there a way to specify that files without test files be included when calculating the coverage percentage?

```
client-functions/cmd/hello-world/main.go:14:    httpHandler     0.0%
client-functions/cmd/hello-world/main.go:20:    main            0.0%
client-functions/pkg/middleware/info.go:16:     infoHandler     100.0%
client-functions/pkg/middleware/info.go:22:     InfoMiddleware  100.0%
client-functions/pkg/middleware/middleware.go:7:Middleware      100.0%
client-functions/pkg/middleware/panic.go:10:    PanicMiddleware 100.0%
total:                          (statements)    84.0%
```

Comment: Are you sure they were not considered in the total percentage ?  You have 4 files with 100% and 2 with 0%.

Comment: Yes, the project as a whole has over 20 files.  Only those with corresponding test files show in the above output.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to specify that files without test files be included when calculating the coverage percentage?

Yes. Actually there is no way to *exclude* them: They are included always.

Comment: Unless there is something I have setup incorrectly, I am not seeing that being the case.  Only those source files with corresponding test files are reported and included in the overall project coverage.

Comment: @Steve Are you taking about the "total (statements)" metric? If so that is already printed by `go test -cover` you do not need to analyse the coverprofile for that.

Comment: So I've found that including "-coverpkg" gives me the results I expect, and includes all source files regardless of whether corresponding test files exist or not.  This is the command that provides a total statement coverage percentage:  "go test -coverpkg=./... ./...".

Comment: @Steve if you can make your comment that mentions the usage `-coverpkg` an answer, it worked for me and I believe it answers your question.